# How to render two components in a single route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to render Projects Component with Home Component on a single page. \

```
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/> 
    <Route path='/Projects' element={<Projects/>}/>
    <Route path='/About' element={<About/>}/>
    <Route path='/MyStack' element={<MyStack/>}/>
    
    <Route path='/Blogs' element={<Blogs/>}/>
    <Route path='/Contact' element={<Contact/>}/>
  </Routes>
  
</div>
```

I don't have any extra button on  navbar for `project` component.
How to render the `project` component and the `home` component on the same page using the same route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping in [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) and rendering both:

```
 <Route path='/' element={<><Home/><Projects/></>}/>
```